# parse json sent by php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

my question may be the duplicate of many questions but i have tried all my options but couldn't get to parse the json that i receive via an Ajax request

hi,

so im getting this json response as a result of Ajax call

```
{
    "audi": [
        "100",
        "200",
        "80",
        "90",
        "a3",
        "a4",
        "a6",
        "a8"
    ]
}
```

this is the json i am receiving following is my one of the attempted options

```
var obj = JSON.parse(html);
            alert("json decoded");

            for(var yahoo in obj)
            {
             alert(obj[yahoo]); // this line gives me 100,200,80,90,...
            }
```

any help is much appreciated ...

EDIT:

here is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "makemodel.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {data:data},
            cache: false,
            async:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (html) {           
            alert("success");           
            var obj = JSON.parse(html);
            alert("json decoded");          
            for(var yahoo in obj)
            {
             alert(obj[yahoo]);
            }

                      }//ajax success ends
           });//ajax ends
```

Comment: lets see your ajax call code? I believe all you need to do is set the dataType property to "json"

Comment: @Ben after setting `dataType` to `json` i dont get to the `alert("json decoded")`

Comment: after setting dataType you no longer need to call JSON.parse as your result will already be a JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the `dataType` option of jQuery's ajax call to `"json"`, jQuery will automatically parse the JSON code. The first argument to your success callback is already the parsed object then.

```
success: function (data) {   
   var s = 0;
   for (var i = 0;i < data['audi'].length;i++) {
       s += parseInt(data['audi'][i]);
   }
   alert("Sum of all audi prices: " + s);
}
```

Comment: tnx im gona try it now...P.S these all are audi models :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get your json data using getJSON, following is the example.

```
var price = 0;
$.getJSON("make_model.php", {data: data}, function(response){
    $.each(response, function(key, value){
        price += value['price'];
    });
});
alert(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this code can help you, too:

```
var obj = jQuery.ajax({
   url: url,
   async: false,
   dataType: 'json'
}).responseText;

for(var yahoo in obj){
   alert(obj[yahoo]);
}
```